# Obtain parent attribute on load of sub-grid form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a form for an Entity A with a sub-grid for Entity B on it. The form for the sub-grid (Entity B) contains an option-set and my requirement is to restrict the values one can select on the Entity B form based on an attribute value of the Entity A. How do I obtain the Entity A attribute value on the Entity B form using JavaScript?

Comment: What if one sets the option set correctly and then the attribute in Entity A changes making the option set no longer valid ?

Comment: That will be taken care of by a plugin which verifies data entered on the form. The problem here is how do I get the attribute on Entity A in the form for Entity B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the SDK.REST.retrieveRecord function. We can get the parent record ID (Here the Entity A) from its lookup field on Entity B (Entity A has a 1:N relationship with Entity B) and retrieve all related records using the REST function above.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the [OData endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx). In this example, I assume to be in a Contact form and retrieve the Relationship Type attribute of the Parent Account.

```
var accountId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('parentaccountid').getValue()[0].id;
var url = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();

// OData url. Note that you have to use Schema Names (it's case-sensitive)
url = url + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'"+accountId+"')?$select=CustomerTypeCode";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url, false); // synchronous call, to keep code short
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.send(null);
var retrievedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

// accountData.CustomerTypeCode.Value now contains the numerical value of the optionset
```

Comment: OData is in fact the easiest way to get data from external records.  However, this should be updated such that you retrieve the optionset value as opposed to the "Name" column, otherwise the retrieved data doesn't do much good.

Comment: @JosephDuty Good point, I switched from Name to Relationship Type